# How to make current date as the parameter instead of directly using it in postgresql?

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql

I have the sql as follow:

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE  etd:: DATE -  CURRENT_DATE<= @ReminderDay
```

However, i don't want **CURRENT_DATE** directly using in this sql,i want it to be used like `@ReminderDay`,because the current date passing from database may be different with the local date time, so I want the current date = `DateTime.Now`.

Currently this parameter of ReminderDay is assigned like this: `new { ReminderDay= 7 }`

Thanks!

---

**Edit:** In other words, how to pass the current date as a parameter in postgresql
instead of directly using the CURRENT_DATE variable in postgresql?

Comment: If you write the condition as `etd::date <= current_date + @ReminderDay` it could make use of an index.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, I try it but it shows this error: `42883: operator does not exist: integer + timestamp without time zone'`

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe,Although this idea does not directly solve the problem, I found another solution based on your response. Let us consider `current_date + @ReminderDay` as a whole and replace them with `@NewReminderDay`,then NewReminderDay can be assigned as follow: `new { NewReminderDay = DateTime.Today.AddDays(7) }`，thank you! But I hope who can explain the original question.

Comment: I cannot answer your original question, but the PostgreSQL error is avoided by using `current_date + @ReminderDay * INTERVAL '1 day'`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe,this solution also solve my original question! Regardless of which side the current date is placed on, it can actually be passed as a parameter, just to transform @ReminderDay to `@ReminderDay * INTERVAL '1 day'`, which is the solution you provide. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Laurenz Albe answered in the comment, I found the key of my issue is the type of `@ReminderDay` not the current date.

Here is the right sql:

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE  etd:: DATE<=  @CurrentDate + @ReminderDay * INTERVAL '1 day'
```

And the parameters of this sql can be written as follow:

```
new {CurrentDate  = DateTime.Now, ReminderDay= 7 }
```